# how to export database in broadleaf framework?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

anyone know about "BroadLeaf", can you help me?
I am using "Broadleaf" framework and convert database from hsql to sql, but I don't how to export database from hsql?
please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to get an external database utility that can connect to an HSQL DB and export the tables you need as SQL Inserts. Once you have the export, you can use native mysql tools to import.
I would recommend DBeaver (https://dbeaver.io/) as the database tool. This article has instructions to export data using DBeaver (https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/two-features-of-dbeaver-that-every-database-manager-should-know/).

I will point out that exporting & importing is only necessary if you have made changes that you would like to keep. If you are using the default demo data, then that data will be loaded into whatever database is being used when the app is started.